# PubNub JS Uncaught Error: Missing uuid parameter. Provide a valid string uuid

Tags: javascript, pubnub

For anyone else who runs into this, if you take the code from [PubNub's JS documenation page](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/sdks/javascript), you will get an error about the UUID in the console and your code won't work. According to the [PubNub blog post](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/all-pubnub-sdks-now-require-unique-identifiers-uuids/), using a UUID was always best practice and is now required. The problem is that their documentation has not been updated so copy/pasting directly from their code sample will fail when using SDK >= 5.0.

The relevant code block is:

```
pubnub = new PubNub({
    publishKey : "myPublishKey",
    subscribeKey : "mySubscribeKey",
    userId: "myUniqueUserId"
}); // this will fail
```

In order to supply the required UUID, change the last parameter like so:

```
pubnub = new PubNub({
    publishKey : "myPublishKey",
    subscribeKey : "mySubscribeKey",
    uuid: "myUniqueUserId" // note "uuid" instead of "userID"
}); // this will work
```

This took hours of debugging to figure out why the PubNub supplied code was not working. Hopefully this information above will help others. As far as I can tell, this applies to *all* PubNub documentation, not just the JS flavor.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. If you ever run into any issues PubNub free support is quite fast. Just email support@pubnub.com and you'll get answers. We monitor Stack Overflow, too, but likely faster going direct to support. I saw a mention of this in our internal channels, so maybe you did contact support. Cheers!

Comment: By the way, I would edit your question above to just be a question. Then add your answer as the official answer (you'll get more Stack Overflow rep points, too, if you care).

Comment: I talked to docs and there was a docs build issue but the entire docs build process has been overhauled and so this sort of thing will never happen again. Apologies for the time lost on this but again, PN Support for the win with saving you time.